# How to "restart" Internet Explorer Service without Rebooting

Tags: internet-explorer, restart

My Internet Explorer 11 often has errors.  It will "freeze up" (no reponse when access any webstie).  It also no reponse even closed it (click "X").
If I kill "iexplore.exe" in taskmananger, then I reopen it, it is still "freeze up".  Howevers, I can use "firefox" to access the internet at this time.
Everytime, I must reboot the computer to recover "Internet Explorer" back to normal.

Is any "Services" related to "Internet Explorer" ?  Such that, I would restart these "Services" instead reboot the computer.

Comment: IE is "freeze up" again and use TaskKill /f /t /im iexplore.exe would recovery IE.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you just stop the single process `"ieexplore.exe"`, there might be some related processes still running.

To kill all IE processes, use `TaskKill /f /t /im iexplore.exe`.

Also, Did you try resetting the settings to default?

Refer to [How to reset Internet Explorer settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/923737).

Answer (score -2):

You can also make a .bat file to easily do it.
1. Open Notepad (Windows+R. Then type "notepad")
2.Copy this text into Notepad (Ctrl+C):
`taskkill /f /IM explorer.exe
start explorer.exe
exit`
3. Go to File>Save As
4. Type in any name with the extension of .bat. Make sure to remove the .txt at the end. (EX: Restart Explorer.bat)
5. Save it
6. Find the file, double-click it.
7. Done :)

Comment: Really? Your answer is basically how-to enter the command from another answer in a batch file? And even get the `iexplore.exe` and `explorer.exe` mixed up?